# data model of event entity in financial industry (Teradata)

Tags: teradata, data-modeling

As for event in banking industry, I design these 3 tables:

```
consumer_event(entity) the columns: event_id(PK), account_number(FK), campaign_event_id, channel_id, Channel_type_code,event_activity_type_code, event_date,event_status_type_code, financial_indicator

financial_event(subtype of consumer_event), the columns: event_id(PK),account_number(FK),event_amount,event_category_type_code,event_country_code,.......

other_events(subtype of consumer_event)
```

now there is performance issue for the event tables: there are 1 billion records of events already and is still growing. what should I do for it? my colleague suggest to split these event table according to time: consumer_event_2021_1H, consumer_event_2020_2H, consumer_event_2020_1H, etc. But this solution bring the complexity of SQL statements, I need to union all these table if I want to select some data from these event table: select * from consumer_event_2021_1H union all select * from consumer_event_2020_2H union all select * from consumer_event_2020_1H..... what is more, the SQL statement is dynamic with the time, the SQL statement will be change next year, because there is new split of the event table.

any suggestion for the design of event table, including sub type design and performance issue? Thanks!

Comment: *Splitting based on time* -> partitioning, e.g. `partition by range_n (event_date between date '2000-01-01-' and date '2035-12-31' each interval '1'day')`

Comment: thanks! it seems that splitting table is not good

Comment: I research this and find why the legacy solution does not use partition features. In my company, the Teradata was introduced at the year of 2000 when there is no partition feature. Now leveraging the partition feature is the better solution

Comment: Well, partitioning was implemented in V2R5, 2002 :-)